# How to replace <i> element with an attribute value inside the same element using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to take an HTML string like this:

`I'm extra <i data-emoji=":)" class="emoji emoji-happy"></i> today!`

and return only this:

I'm extra :) today!

I'm using Javascript for this.

This is how I'm doing it so far:

```
    const emojiRegex = /<i\s.*data-emoji="(.*?)".*\/i>/
    const matches = data.match(emojiRegex)
    const fixed = matches && matches.length > 0
      ? data.replace(matches[0], matches[1])
      : data

    return fixed
```

It does work, but I was wondering if there is a better, safer way of doing it. The first variation of my regex pattern included a check for non alphanumeric characters inside the quotes, like data-emoji="(\W*?)", but then I may also get strings with :S or something like that, so I changed it for "(.*?)", but I'm afraid there will be a case where that might fail.

Anyone knows of a better, safer way?

Comment: in which language you want solution? JavaScript or ecmascript?

Comment: it's okay, maybe change your `.*\/i>` to `.*?\/i>` so you could have multiple emojis in your text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would only change minor things, but your js code looks too complicated, can't you just

```js
data = 'Im extra <i data-emoji=":)" class="emoji emoji-happy"></i> today! But was like <i data-emoji=":(" class="emoji emoji-unhappy"></i> yesterday.';
console.log(data.replace(/<i.*?data-emoji="(.*?)".*?\/i>/g, '$1'));
```

Comment: that worked great! I knew there had to be a simpler way... thank you @Fallenhero